# Как лучше реализовать список стран для asp.net core приложения?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-core

Посоветуйте nuget пакет или другое решение, где содержался бы список стран мира, для дальнейшего использования в приложении. Желательно с наличием стран из недалекого прошлого в том числе (например СССР).
К объекту страны требования минимальны: должен содержать название и можно мини-иконку флага (не обязательно).

Comment: Воспользуйтесь уже готовым: ```CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)```. Но тут, вроде как, не будет стран прошлого.

Comment: Не совсем понял как этим пользоваться.

`Invariant Language (Invariant Country)
Afar
Afar (Djibouti)
Afar (Eritrea)
Afar (Ethiopia)
Afrikaans
Afrikaans (Namibia)
Afrikaans (South Africa)
Aghem
Aghem (Cameroon)
Akan
Akan (Ghana)
Amharic
Amharic (Ethiopia)
Arabic
Arabic (World)
Arabic (United Arab Emirates)
Arabic (Bahrain)
Arabic (Djibouti)
Arabic (Algeria)
Arabic (Egypt)
Arabic (Eritrea)
Arabic (Israel)
Arabic (Iraq)
Arabic (Jordan)` и так далее...
Это немного не то что требовалось. Можно чуть по подробнее как извлечь из этого именно список стран?

Comment: Или вы предлагаете парсить из всего этого названия стран и удалять дубликаты?

Comment: Поискал немного: https://github.com/frankodoom/CountryData.Standard, но непонятно, на английском ли именуются страны или же на каком-то другом. Если бы было на английском, то "Казахстан" был как "Kazakhstan", а не "Qazaqstan"

Comment: Да, это сгодится и недостающие страны можно добавить.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного поискал и нашел следующее решение. Не уверен, все ли тут страны, потому что когда не получается получить регион по `LCID`, то появляется исключение, которое игнорируется.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetCountries()
{
    List<string> cultureList = new List<string>();

    CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);
    foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultures)
    {
        try
        {
            RegionInfo region = new RegionInfo(culture.LCID);

            if (!(cultureList.Contains(region.EnglishName)))
            {
                cultureList.Add(region.EnglishName);
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
    cultureList.Sort();

    return cultureList;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var countries = GetCountries();

    foreach(var country in countries)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(country);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```